How to Extract and Block VPN IP Addresses from NetworkManager Configuration Files Using iptables and Python?
I am seeking assistance with a script to manage VPN IP addresses in Linux NetworkManager.
Objective: To extract IP addresses from VPN configuration files and block them using iptables.
Environment Details:

Location: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

File type: .nmconnection

Target: VPN configuration files only


Current Attempt:
ip=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*)

iptables -A INPUT -s "$ip"  -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$ip" -j DROP


I am seeking assistance with a script to manage VPN IP addresses in Linux NetworkManager.
Objective: To extract IP addresses from VPN configuration files and block them using iptables.
Environment Details:

Location: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

File type: .nmconnection

Target: VPN configuration files only


Current Attempt:
ip=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*)

iptables -A INPUT -s "$ip"  -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$ip" -j DROP

Issues to Resolve:

Need to identify and process only VPN configuration files

Extract individual IP addresses (Example: 137.119.23.205)

Apply iptables rules for each IP separately


Question
What is the recommended method to filter VPN configuration files?
Technical Requirements:

Solution must be implemented in Python

Must handle multiple files

Must process only valid IP addresses


I would appreciate guidance on implementing this functionality correctly and efficiently.
** .nmconnection file**
[connection]
id=jp-free-840006.protonvpn.tcp
uuid=d9a1c788-db09-41a2-8884-9ee3024f
type=vpn
autoconnect=false

[vpn]
ca=/home/user/.cert/nm-openvpn/jp-free-840006.protonvpn.tcp-ca.pem
cipher=AES-256-GCM
connection-type=password
dev=tun
mssfix=0
password-flags=1
proto-tcp=yes
remote=138.199.22.103:7770, 138.199.22.103:443, 138.199.22.103:8443
remote-cert-tls=server
remote-random=yes
reneg-seconds=0
tls-crypt=/home/user/.cert/nm-openvpn/jp-free-840006.protonvpn.tcp-tls-crypt.pem
tunnel-mtu=1500
username=user
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]


When people ask for the contents of a file you should post it to the question it was asked in, not create a new question.

@DourHighArch Hello, stacoverflow closed my question, then forced me to ask again more specific question like this.
